# Explosive Rounds perk in Modern Warfare 2

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In Modern Warfare 2, I was running around knifing the other day when I stumbled upon a gun that said it had explosive rounds as an attachment.  Unfortunately, I died a moment later and never found the gun again.

Does anyone know what gun(s) have the explosive rounds perk? How are they unlocked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MG4 shows as having explosive rounds when equipped with FMJ. So it is sort of a glitch.

Look in the trivia section at the bottom: http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/MG4

Comment: The TAR-21 has a MARS sight instead of a Red Dot sight, and the L86 LSW has a SUSAT sight instead of an ACOG sight. So it's possible they made the MG4 show explosive rounds instead of FMJ on purpose. But I don't know why :P